# Issues with Python / Tinker Please: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a volume per foot calculator using Python and Tkinter. I keep getting this error message. I know it is probably something simple I am overlooking. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Volume Calculator")

def volume_per_foot():
    gallons_per_foot = inside_diameter * inside_diameter / 1029.4
    return (gallons_per_foot)

frame = LabelFrame(root, text="BHA", padx=5, pady=5)
frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

component_label = Label(frame, text="Component")
component_label.grid(row=0)
component = Entry(frame)
component.grid(row=1)

component_length = Label(frame, text="Length")
component_length.grid(row=2)
length = Entry(frame)
length.grid(row=3)

component_outside_diameter = Label(frame, text="Outside Diameter")
component_outside_diameter.grid(row=4)
outside_diameter = Entry(frame)
outside_diameter.grid(row=5)

component_inside_diameter = Label(frame, text="Inside Diameter")
component_inside_diameter.grid(row=6)
inside_diameter = Entry(frame)
inside_diameter.grid(row=7)

submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", command=volume_per_foot)
submit.grid(row=8)

gal_per_foot = Label(frame, text="Gallons Per Foot")
gal_per_foot.grid(row=9)
component_volume = Label(frame)
component_volume.grid(row=10)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "volume.py", line 34, in volume_per_foot
    gallons_per_foot = inside_diameter * inside_diameter / 1029.4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Entry' and 'Entry'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value from the Tk object `Entry` and convert it to a number like:

```
gallons_per_foot = float(inside_diameter.get()) * float(inside_diameter.get()) / 1029.4
```

## Update

You can't get a return value from the button callback. To display the result in a label you could do the following: introduce a `StringVar`, bind it to the label, pass it to the button callback (I am using a closure and a lambda function here) and change its value there after the computation:

```
def volume_per_foot(result_text):
    gallons_per_foot = float(inside_diameter.get()) * float(inside_diameter.get()) / 1029.4
    result_text.set(str(gallons_per_foot))
```

```
result_text = StringVar()
result_text.set("Gallons Per Foot")

submit = Button(frame, text="Enter", command=lambda *args:volume_per_foot(result_text))
submit.grid(row=8)

gal_per_foot = Label(frame, textvariable=result_text)
gal_per_foot.grid(row=9)
```

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explanation. It makes sense to me now, and this solved my problem.

Comment: @LoudEye Glad it helped! Please consider [accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was useful.

Comment: Absolutely. Just another quick one. Do you know how to hide a frame until a button is clicked? I am trying to add components to this volume calculator and I can make them all visible, but sometimes a user will not need a specific component. I have searched the command option in the Tkinter docs, and can't find that command.

Comment: I have done it before with 'if' statements, but not using Tkinter.

Comment: def frame():
    Frame(root, text="BHA", padx=5, pady=5)                                                                                               framebutton = Button(frame, text="Add Component", command=frame)
framebutton.grid(row=11)

Comment: @LoudEye Thank you! [This site](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python-tkinter/how-to-hide-recover-and-delete-tkinter-widgets/) shows how labels can be shown and hidden via buttons. The same should work for a frame or other types of widgets. For checking if a value is visible you can use `pack_info`, `grid_info` and `place_info`. These methods throw an exception if the widget has not been packed or placed.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. You have been extremely helpful.